# How can I make copy-paste event work in a text area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a textbox, a similar one that Twitter has when making a post, including the blue progress bar SVG circle on the bottom right corner that slowly increases, based on the number of letters you type and turns red when you go over the max amount of characters.

Mine works with text so far. However, it breaks a bit when I copy-paste the text in. Here is an example of it.

[image]

Is there any way I can make it work even when I copy-paste the text in?

My code

```js
var orb = (function() {
    var progress = document.querySelector('.progress'),
    textarea = document.querySelector('textarea'),
    counter  = document.querySelector('.counter');


/**
 * GRAB ELEMENTS
 */


var tweetLength = 40,
    warningZone = Math.floor( tweetLength * (1/2) ),
    dangerZone  = Math.floor( tweetLength * (3/4) );


/**
 * SET DASH-ARRAY/OFFSET
 */
var pathLength = Math.PI * ( progress.getAttribute('r') * 2 );

progress.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength + 'px';
progress.style.strokeDasharray  = pathLength + 'px';


/**
 * ON KEYDOWN
 */
textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function( event ) {

    var len = textarea.value.length,
        per = textarea.value.length / tweetLength;

    var handleProgress = function() {
        if ( len <= tweetLength ) {
            var newOffset = pathLength - (pathLength * per) + 'px';
            progress.style.strokeDashoffset = newOffset;
        }
    }
handleProgress();

    var handleColours = function() {
        progress.classList.toggle('warn', len > warningZone && len < dangerZone);
        progress.classList.toggle('danger', len >= dangerZone);
        progress.classList.toggle('tragedy', len == tweetLength);
    }
handleColours();

    var handleCounter = function() {
        counter.textContent = tweetLength - len;
        counter.classList.toggle('danger', len >= tweetLength);
    }
handleCounter();

});

}());
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit; }

body {
  color: #777;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  background-image: url("../img/happy.png");
  background-position: 50% 12em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 85%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0; }

form {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 25em; }

textarea {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-family: inherit;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.333em;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.6em;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px; }

.counter {
  color: #777;
  font-size: 0.8125em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.625em;
  right: 0.80em; }

svg {
  transform: rotate(-90deg); }
  svg circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 1; }

.underlay {
  stroke: #ccc; }

.progress {
  color: #1da1f2;
  stroke-width: 3;
  transition: .2s stroke-width ease-in-out; }

/* colors */
.safe {
  color: #1da1f2; }

.warn {
  color: #ffad1f; }

.danger {
  color: #e0245e; }

.tragedy {
  stroke-width: 5;
  animation: blink .4s ease-out; }

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    stroke-width: 5; }
  10% {
    stroke-width: 10; }
  100% {
    stroke-width: 5; } }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Orb me, baby</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <svg height="90" width="90">
        <circle class="underlay" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="26"></circle>
        <circle class="progress" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="26" stroke="currentColor"></circle>
    </svg>

    <form>
        <textarea cols="10" rows="3" autofocus></textarea>
        <span class="counter"></span>
    </form>

    <script src = "js/app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would handle the "paste" event. The "keydown" event is probably not the best choice, because it fires on things like the backspace key (and note that the backspace key in particular isn't handled well by your code). Probably the "input" event would work better.

Comment: Why is your `/* ON INPUT */` event handler bound to `keydown` instead of... y'know... `input`?

Comment: Still working and testing out the code so it's not perfectly written. I've used the input event before, but forgot to edit the comment, ive fixed that, thanks. This is a type of homework where we had to change the "input" event to make it work with the old IE8.

Comment: Does that mean that your question also has the restriction that it should run on IE8?

Comment: For old IE versions like IE8 & 9 do a redirect to a page that explains they aren't supported and user should use a modern browser

Comment: IE8 did not support `<svg>` anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is better use 'keyup' and i change your js code:

```
 var orb = (function () {
        var progress = document.querySelector('.progress'),
            textarea = document.querySelector('textarea'),
            counter = document.querySelector('.counter');


        /**
         * GRAB ELEMENTS
         */


        var tweetLength = 40,
            warningZone = Math.floor(tweetLength * (1 / 2)),
            dangerZone = Math.floor(tweetLength * (3 / 4));


        /**
         * SET DASH-ARRAY/OFFSET
         */
        var pathLength = Math.PI * (progress.getAttribute('r') * 2);

        progress.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength + 'px';
        progress.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength + 'px';


        /**
         * ON KEYDOWN
         */
        textarea.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {

            var len = textarea.value.length,
                per = textarea.value.length / tweetLength;

            var handleProgress = function () {
                if (len <= tweetLength) {
                    var newOffset = pathLength - (pathLength * per) + 'px';
                    progress.style.strokeDashoffset = newOffset;
                }
            }
            handleProgress();

            var handleColours = function () {
                progress.classList.toggle('warn', len > warningZone && len < dangerZone);
                progress.classList.toggle('danger', len > dangerZone);
                progress.classList.toggle('tragedy', len >= tweetLength);
                if (len >= tweetLength) {
                    progress.style.strokeDasharray = 0 + 'px';
                }else{
                    progress.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength + 'px';

                }
            }
            handleColours();

            var handleCounter = function () {
                counter.textContent = tweetLength - len;
                counter.classList.toggle('danger', len >= tweetLength);
            }
            handleCounter();

        });

    }());
```

Comment: progress.classList.toggle('tragedy', len >= tweetLength);

                if (len >= tweetLength) {
                    progress.style.strokeDasharray = 0 + 'px';
                }else{
                    progress.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength + 'px';

                }

Answer (score 0):

I used `keyup` too. 
I changed `handleCounter()` function and a little bit in `handleProgress()`.
Since you didn't mentioned what to do when the string length is greater than 40 while pasting, I Assumed better to `slice()` a string to first 40 characters and here is the result.
In `handleCounter()`, If user pressed more than 40 characters at a time then `if` condition executes and obviously `len` becomes more than 40 causes negative value in counter but this is managed. It happens because of `keyup`.

```js
var counter = document.getElementsByClassName('counter')[0];
var maxCount = 40;
var warningZone = Math.floor(maxCount * (1 / 2));
var dangerZone = Math.floor(maxCount * (3 / 4));
counter.innerHTML = maxCount;
var textArea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];

var progress = document.querySelector('.progress');
var pathLength = Math.PI * (progress.getAttribute('r') * 2);

progress.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength + 'px';
progress.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength + 'px';

function fun() {
    var len = textArea.value.length;
    var per = textArea.value.length / maxCount;


    var handleProgress = function() {
        if (len <= maxCount) {
            var newOffset = pathLength - (pathLength * per) + 'px';
            progress.style.strokeDashoffset = newOffset;
        } else {
            progress.style.strokeDashoffset = 0;
        }
    }
    handleProgress();

    var handleColours = function() {
        progress.classList.toggle('warn', len > warningZone && len < dangerZone);
        progress.classList.toggle('danger', len >= dangerZone);
        progress.classList.toggle('tragedy', len >= maxCount);
    }
    handleColours();

    var handleCounter = function() {
        if (len > maxCount) {
            counter.classList.toggle('danger', len >= maxCount);
            textArea.value = textArea.value.slice(0, maxCount);
            counter.innerHTML = 0;
        } else {
            counter.innerHTML = maxCount - len;
        }
    }
    handleCounter();

}
```

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    color: #777;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    background-image: url("../img/happy.png");
    background-position: 50% 12em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 85%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}

form {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 25em;
}

textarea {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: inherit;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0.333em;
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.6em;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

.counter {
    color: #777;
    font-size: 0.8125em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0.625em;
    right: 0.80em;
}

svg {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

svg circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 1;
}

.underlay {
    stroke: #ccc;
}

.progress {
    color: #1da1f2;
    stroke-width: 3;
    transition: .2s stroke-width ease-in-out;
}

/* colors */
.safe {
    color: #1da1f2;
}

.warn {
    color: #ffad1f;
}

.danger {
    color: #e0245e;
}

.tragedy {
    stroke-width: 5;
    animation: blink .4s ease-out;
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% {
        stroke-width: 5;
    }

    10% {
        stroke-width: 10;
    }

    100% {
        stroke-width: 5;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <svg height="90" width="90">
        <circle class="underlay" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="26"></circle>
        <circle class="progress" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="26" stroke="currentColor"></circle>
    </svg>
    <form>
        <textarea onkeyup='fun()' cols="10" rows="3" autofocus></textarea>
        <span class="counter"></span>
    </form>
</body>
```

If anything needed, Mention in comment.